# angularjs : how to enable particular component for editing

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS application, I've some textboxes in ng-repeat. You can see the Plunkr snippet [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TyWBV1Yr5Rb0IEY6wdOR?p=preview).
http://plnkr.co/edit/TyWBV1Yr5Rb0IEY6wdOR?p=preview
 When the page loads initially, all the textboxes are disabled for editing i.e. they are not editable. But if the user clicks on, say, the 3rd textbox's 'enable' button, then that textbox should alone become editable. Currently, though am setting the property 'disabled=false' for the textbox in that inde with this code snippet :

```
  $scope.enable = function(index) { 
                          alert("TextBox "+index+" enabled");
                      $scope.records.data[index].disabled="false";
                    };
```

But, still it remains non-editable. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes. First of all change HTML to this:

```
<div ng-repeat="server in records">
    <div ng-repeat="user in server.data">
        <input type="text" ng-model="NameEdit" ng-disabled="user.disabled" placeholder="{{user.name}}" init-from-form>
        <button id="enableButton" ng-click="enable(user)">Enable
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I changed ngDisabled to `ng-disabled="user.disabled"` (no need expression {{ }}) and `ng-click="enable(user)"`. Then controller becomes:

```
$scope.enable = function(user) {
    user.disabled = false; // false must be boolean, not string "false"
};
```

#### Fixed demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/OwFfxmkzHBnmE8Y5TQUi?p=preview